# Install apk with Intent.ACTION_VIEW is downloading but not installing the file

Tags: android

```
Uri myUrl = Uri.parse(stringURL); 
Intent update1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(myUrl);
startActivity( update1 );
```

This enables download of apk file, but after download install does not start. You need to start it manually by clicking download completed in notification bar. This is also solution in most forum answers.

```
Uri myUrl = Uri.parse(stringURL); 
Intent update2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(myUrl,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity( update2 );
```

In this scenario i get message (DDMS): No Activity found to handle intent... I also think that MIME "application/vnd.android.package-archive" is not obligatory. Is this true?
If not, do you have to config http server to make this work. 
Like .htaccess file needs to be updated with:

> AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive

If is it so, do you know any link of apk that i can test, if after download, installation process starts automatically (files on this site are not [samples](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/list) installed).

Is any workaround that I can call install intent from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do you know any link of apk that i can test, if after download, installation process starts automatically

I am not aware that this is possible.

> Is any workaround that I can call install intent from code?

You can download the file yourself, then do an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the local APK file. That, AFAIK, will immediately bring up the installation screen.

Comment: This is why I didn't find any real answer. Ok! Do you know what is best way to download is my algoritm ok? 1. Probably I need to check location where to save (if external SD card exist then on external SD card else on internal or is some simple general procedure). 2. On success I run ACTION_VIEW intent. 3. I probably could receive some kind intend that install was successful??? Is there any tested example?

Comment: @MatejC: "Do you know what is best way to download?" -- HttpClient would be my choice.