# Link directly to another app on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink

How do you link directly to another app **to open it** (the actual app and not the marketplace or appstore reference)? What's the format for both Android and iOS?

Comment: If by link you mean install you can have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552428/install-apk-with-intent-action-view-is-downloading-but-not-installing-the-file)

Comment: I don't mean install... i mean open

Comment: This should be two different questions: one for Android and one for iOS.

Comment: I guess I might have been simplifying the problem.. I had thought there was a universal protocol such as app://com.packagenanme.appname (?)

Answer (score 0):

On android, just create an Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(APP_PACKAGE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No... I'm not trying to start a new activity - just trying to open another app

Comment: @ina: You start another app by opening one of its activities, just as you start another Web app by loading one of its Web pages. That being said, this answer's first line of code is wrong -- you do not create an `Intent` pretending that the app's package is somehow an action string. You need to determine the appropriate `Intent` to use for the app you want to open. That might be by reading the developer docs for that app. Or, you can use `PackageManager` to find a suitable `Intent` for launching the "main" activity in an app via its package.

Comment: hmmm there's nothing like a universal format like this:   android://com.packagename.appname ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you might want to look at [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)
And you might want to search before you ask :D Quicker way for you to find answers most of the time:)

Comment: unless you don't know that you should search for intent of-course, so your are probably quite right about asking :) Couldn't find any good answer unless i included that in my search :D

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourAppURL];
```

for example mail app in iPhone:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://info@iphonedevelopertips.com"]];
```

link to tutorial: [Launching Your Own Application via a Custom URL Scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: And if you want to create your own URLs for your own applications, take a look at this method:
    [- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation]

Here you will find its reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: check my link: Launching Your Own Application via a Custom URL Scheme

Comment: is the only way to launch the app via a custom url scheme? what if the app you want to launch does not have the scheme setup? is there a way to launch it?

Comment: Without custom url scheme you can only open system apps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would go about on th iOS side of things, but for the Android part, refer to this link: [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2780102/450534)

The OP had a similar question and the solution worked for him. Give it a look.

Comment: My bad. I did not realize @erbsman had posted the same link earlier than I did. Mighty sorry fella.